# Why are site and network hat totals different?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

My Winter Bash hat [total on ELU](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/english.stackexchange.com) (25 hats) is different from [that on the whole network](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/network?page=1) (27 hats).

Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you earned the Old Hat and Hello World! hats *outside* of ELU, on different sites, leaving 25 unique to ELU.

You can look at your hats in your profile, and each hat has a list of sites you earned them on:

[image: old hat sites]

Answer (score 5):

Because on the whole network, you've gained two hats that you didn't gain on ELU.

Comment: Yup, "Hello, World!" (gaming) and "Old Hat" (some beta sites) :)